# How to convert int to date in MS Sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an integer in one of the column as 123114, which I need to convert as DATE format (12/31/2014). How can I do it? I even tried to convert it to datetime and then date, but that is not working either. I am running out with errors. Can anyone help me in this.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: post the query that you have tried so that some can tell whats wrong in that @Aparanjit

Comment: how would your "date" look for 01/01/2014 ? 112014 ? Same for 01/11/2014 and 11/01/2014 ?

Comment: And once you figure this out you should change your datatype to be date or datetime. Storing this as an int is painful.

Comment: I agree with both Raphaël and Sean. I would also add, or clarify what Sean said regarding not using INT to store dates, that if you are going to use INT, then the format needs to be YYYYMMDD. And the MM and DD always need to be 2 digits, hence values < 10 need a leading 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @yourdate int
select @yourdate = 20141231
select CONVERT (date,convert(char(8),@yourdate))
```

try this..

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
    @testDate  as int = '123114',
    @StringDate as Char(6) 

set @StringDate = Cast(@testDate as Char(6))

select
    ActualDate = (Substring(@StringDate,1,2) + '/' + Substring(@StringDate,3,2) + '/20' + Substring(@StringDate,5,2))
```

This would assume that the int was formatted as mmddyy, requiring a leading 0 when m < 10 as mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a query, it's hard to give you a definite answer. Presuming your integers are always in a mmddyy format, this should work:

```
declare @a int = 121314
declare @b varchar(10)
select @b = cast(@a as varchar(10))

if len(@b) = 6 --mmddyy
begin
select cast(substring(@b,1,2) + '-' + substring(@b,3,2) + '-' +substring(@b,5,2) as date) as castDate --depends on database collation
select convert(date, substring(@b,1,2) + '/' + substring(@b,3,2) + '/' +substring(@b,5,2), 1) as convertedDate
end
else
begin 
    print 'need something more complicated here'
end
```

You'll definitely want some sort of else condition regardless, to handle bad data, unless your values are pretty tightly constrained.